# Merge list of maps with duplicate keys

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, merge, stream

I have a list of `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` and would like to merge them in a **loop**.
The problem is that each map's key starts from 0 so the keys will be duplicated. The `putAll()` does not work as it overrides the keys and always gives me the last map.

I have seen examples of merging two maps by using Stream but in my case, there might be more than 2 maps. I am trying to generate a merged map that has an incremental key. For example:

Let's say I have 2 maps in the list (could be more) and both keys start from 0 but ends at different values.

1st map, the key starts at 0 ends at 10

2nd map, the key starts at 0 ends at 15

Is it possible to add the second map with the key starting at 11?
In the end, I need a merged map in which the first key starts at 0 and the last key ends at 25.

Comment: HashMap doesn't allow duplicate keys so it will override the keys. What exactly are you trying to achieve here as output?

Comment: I assume you mean merge the string lists of map entries with the same key?

Comment: @RajaShekar edited the question to clarify what I need. The keys should be incremental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of maps, where the keys of each map are integers in range `[0-k], [0-n], [0, r] ...` and your resulting map should a key set in the range of `[0 - (k+n+r..)]` something like below should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   //example list of maps
   List<Map<Integer,List<String>>> mapList = List.of(
           Map.of( 0,List.of("foo","foo"), 
                   1,List.of("bar","bar"), 
                   2,List.of("baz","baz")),
           Map.of( 0,List.of("doo","doo"), 
                   1,List.of("gee","gee"), 
                   2,List.of("woo","woo")),
           Map.of( 0,List.of("cab","cab"), 
                   1,List.of("kii","kii"), 
                   2,List.of("taa","taa"))
   );
   AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
   Map<Integer,List<String>> result = 
           mapList.stream()
                   .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream())
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(list -> ai.getAndIncrement(), Function.identity()));
   result.forEach((k,v) ->{
       System.out.println(k + " : " + v);
   });
}
```

Comment: @Cugomastik You are welcome. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

I'd iterate over any number of maps you have, and then for each map you want to combine, iterate over the entries. For each entry you can use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to conditionally create an empty list for the key, and then call [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) on the value. E.g.:

```java
List<Map<Integer, List<String>>> maps = List.of(
        Map.of(1, List.of("hello")),
        Map.of(2, List.of("world")),
        Map.of(1, List.of("a"), 2, List.of("b"))
);

Map<Integer, List<String>> combined = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<Integer, List<String>> map : maps) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> e : map.entrySet()) {
        combined.computeIfAbsent(e.getKey(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).addAll(e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, the maps are not merged and I am still getting the last map.

Comment: @Cugomastik I suggest providing a [mre] in the question then. The above code definitely merges the maps into one (works in JShell).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a streams approach

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> m1;
Map<Integer, List<String>> m2;
Map<Integer, List<String>> m3;

Map<Integer, List<String>> combined = new HashMap<>();
Stream
    .of(m1, m2, m3)
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .forEach(e -> combined.computeIfAbsent(e.getKey(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
            .addAll(e.getValue()));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what if there are 50 maps to be merged? Can it be used in a loop?

Comment: In case of 50, I expect you will have a list of them. Then you could stream the list. 

`List<Map<Integer, List<String>>> maps`. You could use maps.stream() followed by the rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I adapted the code and tried it out with a map list but still getting the last map only.

Comment: In the above example you will find all the entries in the combined map.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a map, but based on your explanation your ultimate solution and the fact that your keys are now sequential integers starting at 0, you could create just a `List<List<String>>`.  In that case, you could do it like this:

```
List<List<String>> result = mapList.stream()
               .flatMap(map->map.values().stream())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```